# Use PCL Viewer in Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, point-cloud-library

I am trying to show a pcl viewer in a simple Qt project.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
        pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("my_point_cloud.pcd", *cloud);
        pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer("Cloud Viewer");
        //blocks until the cloud is actually rendered
        viewer.showCloud(cloud);
}
```

When I built, there was no link problem, and qt window show correctly. But when I click the pushbutton, the program crashed with no reason. I think my *.dll files should be OK, so what could be the problem?
Thank you